# Matching multiple strings

Tags: python, regex

I am learning Python string operations and trying to convert delimited text into variables.

i.e. `"On Tap: 20 | Bottles: 957 | Cans: 139"`

This string should assign value of 20 to Tap, 957 to Bottles, and 139 to Cans. This string is not fixed and may vary (for example 3 values or 0, also position of Tap, Bottles or Cans can be interchanged).

So far I have developed this:

```
import re

strEx = "On Tap: 20 | Bottles: 957 | Cans: 139"
barServingText = strEx.split('|')
print(barServingText)
for i in barServingText:
    print (i)
    if i.find("Bottles"):
        print("Found Bottles")
        Bottles = re.sub('[^0-9]*','',i)
        print(Bottles)
    elif i.find("Cans"):
        print("Found Cans")
        Cans = re.sub('[^0-9]*','',i)
        print(Cans)
    elif i.find("Tap"):
        print("Found Tap")
        Tap = re.sub('[^0-9]*','',i)
        print(Tap)
```

However it is not working as per my expectations and reassigning the value of Bottles every time.

Output:

```
['On Tap: 20 ', ' Bottles: 957 ', ' Cans: 139']
On Tap: 20
Found Bottles
20
 Bottles: 957
Found Bottles
957
 Cans: 139
Found Bottles
139
```

I have included many `print` statements to debug the code. My purpose is just to assign values to proper variables.

Comment: As you are trying to learn python and trying to convert string into variables therefore your variable should be created from the string automatically not by assigning value of a match into a variable decalred by you. exec should be used ( as far as learning python is concerned)

Comment: can you give example how to?

Comment: watch my answer , i have posted here

Comment: @Maverick_Mrt I have just posted relevant part for my question. Actually I have data with some name and then this data: e.g. 1st record) "A,On Tap: 20 | Bottles: 957 | Cans: 139"  2nd record) "B, On Tap:3" 3rd record) "C , Glasses:5"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` returns `-1` when it can't find string and `-1` is treated as `True` (`bool(-1)` gives `True`) so you have to use `find(...) != -1`

```
import re

strEx = "On Tap: 20 | Bottles: 957 | Cans: 139"
barServingText = strEx.split('|')
print(barServingText)
for i in barServingText:
    print (i)
    if i.find("Bottles") != -1:
        print("Found Bottles")
        Bottles = re.sub('[^0-9]*','',i)
        print(Bottles)
    elif i.find("Cans") != -1:
        print("Found Cans")
        Cans = re.sub('[^0-9]*','',i)
        print(Cans)
    elif i.find("Tap") != -1:
        print("Found Tap")
        Tap = re.sub('[^0-9]*','',i)
        print(Tap)
```

---

BTW: with your data you don't need `re`. You can use `split` (and `strip`)

```
Bottles = i.split(':')[1].strip()

Cans = i.split(':')[1].strip()

Tap = i.split(':')[1].strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `str.find()` method is used for returning the location of the text in a string. If it doesn't find the text, it returns the integer -1. In Python, for checking if on string contains another, you may want to use the syntax `if subString in string:`, like so:

```
...
    if "Bottles" in i:
        print("Found Bottles")
...
```

As the official documentation states:

> For the string and byte types, `x in y`
>    is only true if and only if `x` is a substring of `y`. An equivalent test is `y.find(x) != -1`

So, depending on your preferred coding style and/or particular needs, you can choose between "`x in y`" or "`y.find(x) != -1`"

Answer (score 1):

The following regex should create key value pair for you:

```
r"((.*?):(.*?)(\||$))"
```

The following approach however i think is better suited as it would make it dynamic and can have more than these 3 variables

```
import re

regex = ur"((.*?):(.*?)(\||$))"

test_str = u"On Tap: 20 | Bottles: 957 | Cans: 139"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    s=match.group(2).strip().split(' ')[-1]+"="+match.group(3).strip()
    print(s)
    exec(s)

print(Tap)
print(Bottles)
print(Cans)
```

Comment: I feel like this is somewhat entirely rewriting the OP's code, while he was simply trying to figure out why his code was not working as expected.

Comment: @Ben Morris the statement says : "This string is not fixed and may vary(for example 3 values or 0 value also position of tap, bottles or cans can be interchanged)." thus would that be a good case to iterate thing with hardcoded approach ? exec("%s = %d" % (x,2)) can be used to assign group 3's value to group 2 with some stripping and casting dynamically. My intention is to suggest better approach... therefore I feel the approach tried is not proper